# How to use routes in submit button form - Angular2

Tags: forms, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I'm new to Angular2 and I have been having some doubts about routes.

I'm using Angular Material and I have 2 forms: Login and Signup.
When I click Submit in one of those forms I want to be redirected to a component called Portal.

This is my structure and each component has its own module:

- App

  - Form

    - Login
    - Signup
  - Portal

I thought I could make it work with routerLink but I realized soon enough that it wasn´t possible. I know that I have to pass some event to the ngSubmit, but I'm not sure what...

If someone could explain me the process and guide me through the steps, I'd be very thankful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

First you need to import

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
```

Then inject it in the constructor

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

Then either user ngSubmit event on the form or click event on the button, add the method and at the end of it do this.

```
this.router.navigate(['/portal']);
```

Answer (score 4):

- In the **html** use `ngSubmit` and will just need to call a function like below

  ```
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  ```
- Define the router in '@angular/router'

  ```
  import {Router} from '@angular/router';
  ```
- In the controller put

  ```
  onSubmit() {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/portal');
  }
  ```

Hope this helps

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
accept
My Login and Signup modules are imported in the Form module and I call the tags for each one of them in the form.component.html.

In which files do I have to import the Router ? And in which controller do I have to define the onSubmit() ? And where do I put the tag ?

Given my structure Im not sure where I have to call and put everything...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have followed the angular router guide [here](https://angular.io/guide/router). Most probably your router will look something like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "signup", component: SignupComponent },
  { path: "portal", component: PortalComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Now in LoginComponent you have do what @Jalay Oza provided as an answer. Similarly you have to do the same in SignUpComponent and PortalComponent.

Hope this helps.